# select sum based on month and year with a unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to sum all the values in a column for month 10 which is october, but i seem to have unix timestamp

i tried the following but the value remains 0

```
<?php 
echo $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(amount_paid) FROM invoice WHERE MONTH (  `creation_timestamp` ) = 10) AS invoice');

$query = $this->db->get('invoice'); 
?>
```

..

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice`(
    `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `amount_paid` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `due` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `creation_timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `payment_timestamp` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `payment_method` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `payment_details` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `status` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'paid or unpaid',
    PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: show schema as outputted by db engine. Show sample data.

Comment: I am actually struggling with that currently. SHOW COlumns is that right ?

Comment: `show create table invoice`

Comment: I posted the result i got is that fine ?

Comment: perfect, now what do some of those timestamp values look like

Comment: 1446940800 a sample timestamp from the table.

Comment: query to store the timestamp 
`date('d M,Y', $row['timestamp']"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a shot as we are looking for the sum for October 2015 (I think)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-01'); -- '1443672000'
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-31 23:59:59'); -- 1446350399
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-11-01'); -- '1446350400'
```

Note the above values

```
drop table invoice2;
create table invoice2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    amount decimal(12,2) not null,
    ts int(11) not null -- from unix timestamp
);

-- truncate table invoice2;
insert invoice2(amount,ts) values 
(10,unix_timestamp('2015-10-01')),
(10,unix_timestamp('2015-10-01')),
(3310,unix_timestamp('2015-11-01')),
(3310,unix_timestamp('2015-11-01')),
(44410,unix_timestamp('2016-01-01')),
(5510,unix_timestamp('2016-02-01')),
(6610,unix_timestamp('2016-02-01'));
```

So you want something in the following flavor for October 2015 amounts:

```
select sum(amount) as theSum 
from invoice2 
where month(from_unixtime(ts))=10  
and year(from_unixtime(ts))=2015;
+--------+
| theSum |
+--------+
|  20.00 |
+--------+
```

---

the function of interest is **get_sum()**

### Codeigniter Model

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class department_model extends CI_Model{

 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
 }

 //read the department list from db
 function get_department_list()
 {
      $sql = 'select var_dept_name, var_emp_name from tbl_dept, tbl_emp where tbl_dept.int_hod = tbl_emp.int_id';
      $query = $this->db->query($sql);
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
 }

 // get the sum of amount based on parameters month and year passed
 function get_sum($month,$year) 
 {    $myQuery="select sum(amount) as theSum from invoice2 where month(from_unixtime(ts))=$month  
                and year(from_unixtime(ts))=$year";
      $query = $this->db->query($myQuery);

      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
 }
```

}

Comment: It Does work, How come it works for Table invoice and displays the sum?        
`SELECT SUM( amount_paid ) AS theSum
FROM invoice
WHERE MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =10
AND YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) =2015`

Comment: you are saying it works now right. It does cuz we fixed it !

Comment: Yes it does. All i have to do now if figure out how to convert it to codeigniter query. Thanks Drew you took your time and helped me. Appreciate your time and effort

Comment: anytime boss. Just downloaded codeigniter a few hours ago. Playing around with it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is some problems in your **query** and **code** as well. when you execute your **query** directly on database it is giving error. Also for custom queries we have to use `$this->db->query()` function in CI. Below is the correct query code snippet.

```
<?php 
   echo $this->db
             ->query('SELECT SUM(amount_paid) AS invoice FROM invoice WHERE MONTH (  `creation_timestamp` ) = 10 ')
             ->row()->invoice;
?>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. i will try to change my whole query